# Mockito never() not working with andThen rxjava2

Tags: unit-testing, junit, kotlin, mockito, rx-java2

I am testing a fairly simple piece of code written in Kotlin:

```
o1.updateUser(params)
     .andThen(o2.reload())
```

When updateUser fails I expect that reload will not be executed. But when testing with Mockito 2 and jUnit 5 there is an invocation of said mock.

the mocking is done like that:

```
given(o1.updateUser(user)).willReturn(Completable.error(IllegalArgumentException())
given(o2.reload()).willReturn(Completable.complete())
```

Now the problem is that the code behaves as expected, meaning that in this case o2 is never actually called, but while unit testing Mockito claims that there was an invocation of o1.

Test assertion looks as follows:

```
verify(o2, never()).reload()
```

Did I do something wrong here? Is there a way around this? Am I understanding the operator somehow incorrectly?

Comment: I think `verify(o2, never()).reload()` is just a bad test for this scenario. For example, you could have an implementation `o1.updateUser(params).andThen((CompletableObserver cs) -> o2.reload())` which would pass the test, but should not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you wrote in the test is actually:

```
Completable c2 = o2.reload(); 
o1.updateUser(params).andThen(c2);
```

What you probably wanted is:

```
o1.updateUser(params).andThen(Completable.defer(() -> o2.reload()));
```

This way, `o2.reload()` gets only called if the execution of `andThen` completes normally and subscribes to the deferred `Completable`.